# flutter gif, only play when commanded

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Is there a way to grab a gif from image.network on flutter and have it activated when we click on a button?

for example

```
body: Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
        child: Image.network(
            'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/04/44/fa/0444fa178b78ff5d3229b1807a1ae0af.gif'),
      ),
```

I would like the initial image of the gif to remain and only play when I touch a button.
Thank you so much

Comment: See if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61467478/stop-gif-animation-on-click-in-flutter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop GIF animation on click in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61467478/stop-gif-animation-on-click-in-flutter)